# Python for loop- why does i goes to 6 then goes to 3 again?

Tags: python, for-loop, range

Please explain how does for loop work.
i know how to solve the problem, using both while loop and for loop(commented code)

```
def decode(string):
    aux = ''
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if(string[i] == '['):
            num = ''
            i+=1
            print(i,"lol")
            while(string[i].isdigit()):
                num+=string[i]
                i+=1
                print(i,'inside')
            aux+= string[i]*int(num)
            i+=1
            print(i)
        #elif string[i].isalpha():
        else:
            print(i,'else')
            aux += string[i]
    return aux

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(decode("AB[12c]d[2E][4F]g"))
```

Shell

- >>> 0 else
- >>> 1 else
- >>> 3 lol
- >>> 4 inside
- >>> 5 inside
- >>> 6
- >>> 3 else
- >>> 4 else
- >>> 5 else
- >>> 6 else
- >>> 7 else
- >>> 9 lol
- >>> 10 inside
- >>>  11
- >>> 9 else
- >>>    10 else
- >>>  11 else
- >>>  13 lol
- >>>    14 inside
- >>>   15
- >>>   13 else
- >>>  14 else
- >>>  15 else
- >>> 16 else
- >>>  ABcccccccccccc12c]dEE2E]FFFF4F]g

how does that work? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your for in range loop will iterate exactly the number of times of the length of the string you pass**... *You cant cause the loop to jump further ahead by incrementing i within the loop... Its not the same things as a for i = 0 to i < length*...

Think about your output this way...

**first iteration** in range gives you ...

> > > 0 else

**second iteration** in range gives you...

> > > 1 else

**third iteration** in range gives you...

> > > 3 lol
> > >       4 inside
> > >       5 inside
> > >       6

**the fourth iteration** ***goes back to 3 because the loop is zero indexed and its the fourth iteration so you get***...

> > > 3 else

In order for loop with i changing by steps different than one, you can specify the steps in the range... eg.

```
for i in range(0,10,2):
```

**In summary:
You are thinking that your manipulation of i within the loop should carry over to when you get back to the top of the loop, but it does not, it merely increments by one from the last time you were at the top of the loop.**